# Could not resolve com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to use `com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5` but it gives me an error saying :

```
Could not resolve com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5.
 Required by:
     project :app
  > Could not resolve com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/navasmdc/MaterialDesign/1.5/MaterialDesign-1.5.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/navasmdc/MaterialDesign/1.5/MaterialDesign-1.5.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

This is what I have in `build.gradle` :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 21
    versionName "1.0.4.1"
    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            includeCompileClasspath false
        }
    }
}

flavorDimensions "pro"

productFlavors {
    pro {
        applicationId = "com.javiersantos.mlmanagerpro"
    }

}
flavorDimensions "basic"
productFlavors {
    basic {
        applicationId = "com.javiersantos.mlmanager"
    }
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        versionNameSuffix '-debug'
    }
}

lintOptions {
    disable 'MissingTranslation'
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
}

repositories {

mavenCentral()
maven { url 'http://guardian.github.com/maven/repo-releases' }
maven {
    url "https://maven.google.com"
}
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'

//    implementation group: 'com.github.navasmdc', name: 'MaterialDesign', version: '1.5'

implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
implementation('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.3@aar') { transitive = true; }
implementation('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.5.3@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation 'com.github.yukuku:ambilwarna:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7'
implementation 'xyz.danoz:recyclerviewfastscroller:0.1.3'
implementation 'com.yalantis:phoenix:1.2.2'
implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.6.1@aar') { transitive = true; }
implementation 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:1.2.0.1@aar'
implementation('net.rdrei.android.dirchooser:library:3.0@aar') { transitive = true; }
implementation('com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:5.2.1@aar') { transitive = true; }
annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.2'
implementation 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
}
```

Why should I get authorized for using a library?

**Note:** I have tried putting `jcenter()` and `google()` too.

Comment: can you please upload your build.gradle file(project)?

Comment: My `ping jitpack.io` is too low (450ms). Can it happen because of that?

Comment: upload your build.gradle file first then I will let you know

Comment: Actually this app is not mine. It is the source code of MLManager app.

Comment: Look at last line in the file. That's where I have put that dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library is an old one and you should use modern material design components that android has presented in its core and packages like `androidx`.

However main issue with your error is that the repository has added authorization and you need to have credentials(username + password) to get access. As I told library is old and the last contribution has happened about 4 years ago Thus author may be put credentials recently and forgot to give access to library.

If you really need to use this library [here](https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/com/github/navasmdc/MaterialDesign/1.5/MaterialDesign-1.5.aar) is the link of its aar file, download it and add it manually to your gradle project.

Comment: Which folder should I put it in?

Comment: I added through Project Structure. Thanks alot. +1